# How to show my app's launch image in physical iPhone 4 device, not just in simulator

Tags: image, launch, iphone-4

I added two launch image files, Default.png (320x480) and Default@2x.png (640x960), to Resources in my app. It shows fine in the Simulator, but won't show in the iPhone4 device. It just shows a black screen before the app finishes launching. I even added these entries in .plist file, but still not working.

Can you tell me how I could solve this problem? Is there anything else I need to configure in my app to make it show on the device?

Thanks,
Harry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that they are included as resources in your build target. Given they are showing in the Simulator, I presume you've dragged them into the "Launch Images" section of your build target so that you can see the preview, just under the App icons? If so, you may simply need to do a clean build (Product > Clean) before they will copy to the device.

Comment: I think they are included. Whenever I added new image resources, they're shown in both targets whether run in simulator or device. Thanks for the quick reply though.

Comment: Updated answer with some further possibilities.

Comment: Thanks. It finally works. I did a clean build, and then select the Active Configuration to "Release" instead of "Debug", then it shows on the device.

Answer (score 0):

I have as this problem .. I solve it with:

1. put capital first litter .
2. click on image and from ( File Inspector ) right menu .. choose ( Make Localized ) button .

rerun ,,, and enjoy

Answer (score 0):

I just had to do a clean build and I also had to clean the build folder.  To clean press Command+Shift+C to Clean the Build Folder press Command+Option+Shift+C